# How to use 5G module as an interface?

Tags: networking, drivers, ubuntu-core

I am using Ubuntu core 20 and 5G module called Simcom SIM8202G-M2 (it connects via M2 connector but eventually uses USB protocol).

After plugging it in, I can see from the dmesg that drivers were loaded correctly according to https://bitbucket.org/storjor/techship_linux_drivers/src/master/simcom_qmi_wwan/

```
[   48.344895] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   48.344975] option 1-6:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   48.360440] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   48.360653] option 1-6:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   48.360716] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   48.360859] option 1-6:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   48.360908] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   48.361047] option 1-6:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   48.361098] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[   48.361231] option 1-6:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   48.361290] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
```

lsusb command also sees it correctly:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1e0e:9001 QCOM SDXPRAIRIE-MTP _SN:675A1860

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=05 Cnt=03 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1e0e ProdID=9001 Rev=04.14
S:  Manufacturer=QCOM
S:  Product=SDXPRAIRIE-MTP _SN:675A1860
S:  SerialNumber=0123456789ABCDEF
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=30 Driver=option
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=option
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=option
I:  If#=0x3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=option
I:  If#=0x4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=option
I:  If#=0x5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qmi_wwan
```

Also I have plugged in my sim card which supports 5G and I wonder how can I start using 5G as an interface to communicate with the world?

Comment: Eish man, this is a big topic. You will need to do some Googling first, get it going, then ask specific questions to get decent answers. You can issue AT commands directly to the modem over the command serial port (of the many created when you plug device, speak to each /dev/ttyUSBx in turn and send "AT" to get back "OK"). Should auto-detect baud rate - try 56k, 38k etc., but read docs to see if baud is fixed. Also see things like PPP and Wvdial to do this for you.

Comment: Can you post output from mmcli when modem with sim-card are inserted in?